# Convert a matrix to a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, vector, matrix

What is the most elegant way of converting a matrix to a list, where each element of the list is a vector containing the elements in a row of the matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of approaches

Assuming your matrix is called `foo`

`lapply(seq_len(nrow(foo)), function(x) foo[x,])`

or less efficiently.

`lapply(apply(foo,1,list), unlist)`

Answer (score 3):

Just for the fun of it, here's the shortest syntax I could think of:

```
split(x, 1:nrow(x))
```

Or using the `plyr` package:

```
aaply(x, 1, list)
```

These are slower than @mnel's solutions though (especially the `aaply()` one).

Comment: or  alply(foo, 1)  would do it

Comment: Nice. Seems to be faster too. Still way slower than using `lapply()` though (or even `split()`).